# How to implement stochastic depth, and randomly dropout an entire convolutional layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement this idea: https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09382.
The basic idea is to drop out a Conv2D layer during training based on a "keep prob", like Dropout.
I thought I could do it with a custom layer like this:

```
class StochasticConv2D(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StochasticConv2D, self).__init__()
        self.conv2D = layers.Conv2D(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, training, keep_prob):
        if training and (np.random.uniform() > keep_prob):
            return inputs
        return self.conv2D(inputs)
```

When I try that with training = True, I get this error:

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

If I get that working, I'm not quite sure how to implement the non-training mode. Do I define the model a second time with training = false and load the weights saved in training? And if I pass validation_data to model.fit(), how can "training" be set to false when it runs the validations?

Answer (score 2):

To randomly freeze filters, you can just make a `tf.keras.layers.Dropout` layer with the shape of the convolutional filters' number of channels. Here, we have 10:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10, 3, input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.5, noise_shape=(1, 1, 1, 10))])

x = np.random.rand(1, 28, 28, 1)

np.max(model(x, training=True), axis=(1, 2))
```

```
array([[-0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.53856176, -0.        ,
        -0.        ,  0.16301194, -0.        ,  0.76797724,  0.54769045]],
      dtype=float32)
```

These are all the max values of the 10 convolutional filters. You see that half of these are just zeroes.

To dropout a layer, you can do something similar:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

conv_dropout_layer = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, 3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.5, noise_shape=(1, 1, 1, 1))])

x = np.random.rand(1, 28, 28, 1)

model(x, training=True)
```

Half the time, all these weights will be frozen.

To return either the identity of the convolution result, here's what you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class StochasticConv2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        super(StochasticConv2D, self).__init__()
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.conv2D = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding='SAME', **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        coin_toss = tf.random.uniform(())
        return tf.cond(tf.greater(.5, coin_toss), lambda: inputs, lambda: self.conv2D(inputs))


x = np.random.rand(1, 7, 7, 10)

s = StochasticConv2D(10, 3)

s(x, training=True).shape
```

Comment: Wait, you meant dropout a convolutional layer or filter?

Comment: Dropout a convolutional layer.

Comment: Oh. See edit. That's actually much easier.

Comment: Thanks - I'll study that and try to understand it!

Comment: This is not the concept of the stochastic depth paper, in this case if you drop the entire layer, it produces only zeros, so the network will not train. In stochastic depth, when a layer is dropped, its replaced by the identity function, so training works.

Comment: I didn't read the paper, I did what OP described. The network will train if it's not sequential

Comment: Dr.Snoopy is right. What I'm trying to do is drop out a Conv2D layer that is in the middle of a network. Say there are three layers: Conv2D_1, Conv2D_2 and Conv2D_3. I would like Conv2D_2 to randomly drop out in training only. When it drops out, it is replaced by the identity function.

Comment: How will you handle the fact that a convolutional operation changes the tensor shape?

Comment: I would only apply it to an operation that doesn't change the shape (padding='same' etc.).

Comment: The network is specifically designed so the shape problem does not happen (like using appropriate padding), its basically an extension of residual networks.

Comment: I edited my answer. It's only going to work if the previous layer has the same number of filters though

Comment: Thanks. I modified that a little to add a keep_prob parameter. But how will it know to only skip the layer in training?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it (modified version of previous solution):

```
class StochasticConv2D(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, keep_prob, **kwargs):
        super(StochasticConv2D, self).__init__()
        self.keep_prob = keep_prob
        self.conv2D = layers.Conv2D(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        if keras.backend.learning_phase():
            coin_toss = tf.random.uniform(())
            return tf.cond(tf.greater(coin_toss, self.keep_prob), lambda: inputs, lambda: self.conv2D(inputs))
            
        return self.conv2D(inputs)
```

Comment: Yes, this is just an update to your suggestion, so thanks very much for that! The keep_prob argument could go either place, but I agree it makes more sense in the constructor. I don't think the logic is wrong though. Say keep_prob = 0.8. Then if coin_toss > keep_prob it returns inputs, so there is a 0.2 chance of returning inputs, which is correct. I updated the solution above accordingly.

Comment: Done! And thanks again - you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There's a StochasticDepth layer from [`tensorflow_addons`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/StochasticDepth)

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
residual = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                                  activation="relu",
                                  padding='SAME')(inputs)
x = tfa.layers.StochasticDepth()([inputs, residual])
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
residual = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                                  activation="relu",
                                  padding='SAME')(x)
x = tfa.layers.StochasticDepth()([x, residual])
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, 
                                activation="softmax")(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.summary()

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1).astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 28, 28, 1).astype("float32") / 255

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                    batch_size=64, epochs=2, 
                    validation_split=0.2)
```